# android - record of background activity

Tags: android, record, framebuffer

I am trying to record meetimg application in the background. The application is not shown on the display, it is in the background. Something like record an app with xvfb in linux.

Is it possible ? The backgroud app is able to render in background? Is it possible to forword the audio to the recorder (the user will not listen while he record)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to record?  Audio from an application?  The screen of an application?  Both?  Is your application in the background or the application you're trying to record?  (if the latter, Android applications don't render in the background)

Comment: I want to record the application meeting that in the background. There is a way to run the app in virtual framebuffer like xvfb?